# C#: Resource utilization in Parallel For

Tags: c#, string, parallel-processing

I am trying to do a unique check in a **Parallel For** to make the process faster. Will this actually do my unique check?

Following is my code:

```
List<string> uniqueCheck = new List<string>();

Parallel.For(1, Rows.Length, i => {
    if (Rows[i].Length != 0)
    {
        string[] item = Rows[i].Split(delimiter.ToCharArray());

        if (!uniqueCheck.Contains(item[0].ToLower().Trim()))
        {
            uniqueCheck.Add(item[0].ToLower().Trim());
            dtUnqiueRows.Rows.Add(item);
        }
    }
});
```

I am not sure how **Parallel For** works but I wanted to make sure whether the !uniqueCheck.Contains(...) condition will work as expected or not.

Please comment on this and post any code if this will not work.

Comment: How many rows is this? I'm not so sure that it will actually be faster to use Parallel.For for this use case.

Comment: There are 1.6 Million Rows.

Comment: You can try this:
`var delimiters = delimiter.ToCharArray();`
`var dtUnqiueRows = Rows.Select(row => row.Split(delimiters)[0].Trim().ToLower()).AsParallel().Distinct()).ToList();`

Comment: @mortb: Thanks for you valuable comment. I will definitely try this.

Comment: I was wrong about where to put the AsParallel call, see the answer below

Comment: `List<string>` isn't thread safe so it's possible that a call to `Contains` running in one thread won't find a duplicate which is added in a different thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some test code using Guids.
The reason you want to use Distinct() is that it will use a Hashset and not a list to keep track of the unique items. 
Hashset probably much faster than your uniqueCheck list for large row count.

As you can see in the results it is slightly faster than without parallelism if you write `guids.AsParallel` but slower if you write `Select(....).AsParallel()`.
Here is the code with results:

**Edit**: added `Select(... regex..)` to create a list with more "key duplicates"

```
   var guids = Enumerable.Range(1, 1600000).Select(_ => Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper()).ToList();
guids = guids.Select(g => Regex.Replace(g, @"^([0-9A-F])[^\-]+", "$1$1$1$1")).ToList();
var delimiters = "-".ToCharArray();
    var delimiters = "-".ToCharArray();

var w = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var x = guids.Select(guid => guid.Split(delimiters)[0].ToLower()).Distinct().ToList();
Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed); // 1.80 seconds 

w = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var y = guids.Select(guid => guid.Split(delimiters)[0].ToLower()).AsParallel().Distinct().ToList();
Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed); // 1.67 seconds 

w = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var z = guids.AsParallel().Select(guid => guid.Split(delimiters)[0].ToLower()).Distinct().ToList();
Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed); // 0.75 seconds
```

**Edit**: here is a solution for selecting the first row with the unique key

```
// for selecting the first row which has unique "key"

var w = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var a = guids.GroupBy(guid => guid.Split(delimiters)[0].ToLower()).Select(grp => grp.First()).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed); // 0.65 seconds 

w = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var b = guids.AsParallel().GroupBy(guid => guid.Split(delimiters)[0].ToLower()).Select(grp => grp.First()).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed); // 0.83 seconds
```

Comment: Here from the above example which you have given, I am only getting the first element of the splitted guid. I want the entire guid splitted in an array based on the given delimiter after unique check. How do I do that..?

Comment: I added two GroupBy statements that will select the first "total" guid for each unique "key". I guess that is what you want. I also tweaked the guid list with a regex so that the guid list will contain many duplicate keys.

Comment: Yes it did. Now the code is small and manageable. Fast too... :)